# Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Show that $\mathrm{ann}_{R}(R/I)=I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to show that $\mathrm{ann}_{R}(R/I)=I$, but not sure whether I am "cheating".

I can do the inclusion $I\subseteq \mathrm{ann}_{R}(R/I)$. What I am concerned about is $\mathrm{ann}_{R}(R/I)\subseteq I$.

So, let $\rho\in \mathrm{ann}_{R}(R/I)$, then for all $r+I\in R/I$, we have $$\rho(r+I)=(\rho r)+I=0+I.$$ We have to show $\rho\in I$. Now here is the problem, if I want to have $\rho\in I$, it has to be the case that $\rho+I=0+I$. And it is only possible if $r=1$ in $(\rho r)+I=0+I$. But initially I assumed for all $r+I\in R/I$, but now it is only possible for a specific $r$, so $r$ is no longer general.

My questions:
1. Is my reasoning true? Why and why not?
2. If is it not correct, then how can I fix it? How can I finish the proof?
3. In general proof strategy, can I pick a particular value while I had originally set the value to be arbitrary?

Thanks!

Comment: If something is true for all $r$ (namely that $\rho r + I = I$) then it is in particular true for some $r$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that all you want to conclude is that $\rho \in I$. By judicious selection of $r + I$ (namely $r=1$), you've seen that $\rho 1 + I = I$, and by definition this means that $\rho \in I$.